javascript map function creates extra comma
This is my html file :


  function showMovies(){
    const movies = [
    {title: 'a nice movie', year: 2020, rating: 4.5},
    {title: 'another nice movie', year: 2021, rating: 4.8},
    {title: 'just another movie', year: 2022, rating: 4.2}
  ];
  
  let html ="";
  html = movies.map(function(m) {
    return "<li>" + m.title + '-' + m.year + "-"  + m.rating + "</li>";
  });

  html = "<ul>" + html + "</ul>";
  
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = html;
  
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>  
  </head>
  <body onload="showMovies()">
    <h2>List of movies</h2>
    <div id="list"></div>
    <script src="movies.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



When I preview the page, I have extra commas like in the image below :

Is this an expected outcome with map function? Should I chain some joining/splitting fucntions to get rid of the extra commas?

.map returns an array, so you are combining string with array which is like .join.

The .map() function returns an array, not a string. When you use it as a string to form the HTML, it will implicitly be joined with commas separating the values. You can instead call .join("") yourself with an empty string to avoid that.

A map of an array returns an array. Then when it's stringifed ( I believe by concatenating with other strings), it uses the default delimiter, which is a comma. You'd need to manually join your html array into a string with an empty string as a delimiter. html = "<ul>" + html.join("") + "</ul>";

"javascript map function creates extra comma" - map does nothing with commas - it's what you're doing with the result that's the issue.

That was a stupid mistake of me . Also there must be a way to accept all comments as answers.

When you do this:
html = "<ul>" + html + "</ul>";

html was an array, but you're treating it as a string.  In doing so, JavaScript is representing it as a set of comma-separated values.
Instead of implicitly converting the array to a string, you can explicitly join it to a string:
html = "<ul>" + html.join("") + "</ul>";


Sometimes, especially in loops, it's actually easier to create the elements programmatically, like this:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showMovies);

function showMovies() {
  const movies = [{
      title: 'a nice movie',
      year: 2020,
      rating: 4.5
    },
    {
      title: 'another nice movie',
      year: 2021,
      rating: 4.8
    },
    {
      title: 'just another movie',
      year: 2022,
      rating: 4.2
    }
  ];

  const list = document.createElement('ul');
  list.append(...movies.map(({
    title,
    year,
    rating
  }) => Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {
    textContent: `${title}-${year}-${rating}`
  })));

  document.getElementById('list').append(list);
}
<h2>List of movies</h2>
<div id="list"></div>




Instead of using .map() like that. You could create a function that builds your <ul>, just use forEach and concatenate each item as a <li> then close the </ul> tag when finished and return the HTML


function showMovies() {
  const movies = [{
      title: 'a nice movie',
      year: 2020,
      rating: 4.5
    },
    {
      title: 'another nice movie',
      year: 2021,
      rating: 4.8
    },
    {
      title: 'just another movie',
      year: 2022,
      rating: 4.2
    }
  ];

  let html = buildHTML(movies);
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = html;
}

function buildHTML(moviesList) {
  let myUl = "<ul>"
  moviesList.forEach(m => {
    myUl += "<li>" + m.title + '-' + m.year + "-" + m.rating + "</li>";
  })
  myUl += "</ul>"
  return myUl;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="showMovies()">
  <h2>List of movies</h2>
  <div id="list"></div>
  <script src="movies.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



